# Is there a way to mock method calls on a local object

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-boot-test

I am using Mockito framework to write test cases for an existing spring-boot project.

In one of the class, they have created local instance of `rest-template` inside a function instead of `@Autowiring`.

```
public LatxDetails getLatxCaseDetail_Fallback(String endpoint, Map<String, String> requestMap) {

//some code

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(kxCreateEndpoint, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class);

//some code
```

I am unable to mock the rest call.I can't add any other external jars or change code. How should I proceed? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution would be to inject the `RestTemplate` instead of instantiating one locally but as you said that you can not change the existing code I would suggest to use [PowerMock with Mockito](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito#how-to-mock-construction-of-new-objects) to replace the constructor call of the `RestTemplate` using the [`PowerMockito.whenNew`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.7.4/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html#whenNew-java.lang.Class-) method.

E.g.

```
RestTemplate restTemplateMock = Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(RestTemplate.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(restTemplateMock);
```

and then doing the `when` setup on the restTemplateMock object.

As mentioned by Strelok in the comments: in order to use PowerMockito you need to run the test with the `PowerMockRunner` by annotating the test class with `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PrepareForTest`.

E.g.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(RestTemplate.class)
public class Test {
```

Comment: Perhaps you can extend your answer to note that you must run the tests with PowerMockitoRunner and crucially you must annotate the test with @PrepareForTest(ClassThatCreatesTheNewInstance.class). This would save a lot of headache for someone who doesn't know how PowerMockito works.

Answer (score 0):

Either replace your RestTemplate with a Mock or create a spy of it:

```
// Mock
RestTemplate restTemplate = Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);

// Spy
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
RestTemplate spy = Mockito.spy(restTemplate);
```

You can mock the `exchange` method like usual:

```
// mock
doReturn(...).when(restTemplate).exchange(...)

// spy
doReturn(...).when(spy).exchange(...)
```